# Python Flask sortable list result from jquery

Tags: jquery, python, jquery-ui-sortable

I manage to get to the point where the edit route gets invoked, but I cant figure out, how to actually receive the data from the site, Im pretty confused if I have to use ajax or json too...

HTML:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
axis: 'y',
update: function (event, ui) {
    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');

    // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
    $.ajax({
        result: data,
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/edit/'
    });
}
});
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>

<ul id="sortable">
{% for elem in tables_list %}
    <li id={{ elem['id'] }}> {{elem['table_name']}} ({{ elem['norm_cap'] }} / {{ elem['max_cap'] }})</li>
{% endfor %}

</ul>


{% endblock %}
```

Flask:

```
@app.route("/edit/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit():
    if request.method == "POST":
        priority_list = request.args.get('result', [])
        return "Thank You"
```

once I'll get the data, I know what to do with mysql, I just need to be able to get what the script posts.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use getlist (similar to Django's getList) to get the data from AJAX.

Since you are using jQuery to send this request, be sure to flag your ajax request as traditional either by setting
`jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`
or altering your current code to...

```
// POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
$.ajax({
    result: data,
    traditional: true,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/edit/'
});
```

Inside your Flask application alter the existing code to read

```
@app.route("/edit/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit():
    if request.method == "POST":
            priority_list = request.values.getlist('results')
            return "Thank You"
```